# Undefined when trying to pull json img

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to populate a div with NASA's picture of the day using their API.

I've written the AJAX request in jQuery but when I execute the function, I just get links to `undefined`

What is missing in my function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        //AJAX
        var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=KmKClvkvdi3Ug54cIAhw8sd43XnYVitmTz2lAjGw"
        function nasaData(data) {
            var photoHTML = '<div>';
            $.each(data, function(i, photo) {
                photoHTML += '<a href="' + photo.url + '">';
                photoHTML += '<p>"' + photo.explaination + '"</p>'
                photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.copyright + '"> </a>';
            });
            photoHTML += "</div>";
            $('#photos').html(photoHTML);
        }
        $.getJSON(url, nasaData);
    }); //end eventsubmit
});
```

Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flicker.css">
        <title>Testing Access to Flicker API</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="flicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">Welcome to the  API search test.</h1>
            <h4 class="text-center">Use the form below to search the open NASA API based.</h4>
            <form>
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class='button' />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="photos"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess you need to request that json on the server side, I don't see any CORS header Access-control-allow-origin: *  to allow you to do a request inside a browser.

Comment: @progysm CORS isn't an issue here.  The server is indeed properly returning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for whatever the referring domain is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use **$.each()** as everything is already in **data** parameter.

Here you go.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        //AJAX
        var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=KmKClvkvdi3Ug54cIAhw8sd43XnYVitmTz2lAjGw"
        function nasaData(data) {
            var photoHTML = '<div>';
            photoHTML += '<a href="' + data.hdurl + '">';
            photoHTML += '<p>"' + data.title + '"</p>';
            photoHTML += '<img src="' + data.hdurl + '"> </a>';
            photoHTML += "</div>";
            $('#photos').html(photoHTML);
        }
        $.getJSON(url, nasaData);
    }); //end eventsubmit
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flicker.css">
    <title>Testing Access to Flicker API</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="flicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Welcome to the  API search test.</h1>
        <h4 class="text-center">Use the form below to search the open NASA API based.</h4>
        <form>
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                <input type="submit" class='button' />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="photos">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**N.B.:** To play with **API** using **console.log()** is a better option to check the passing data.

Codepen URL: http://codepen.io/arsho/full/ZOXago/

Comment: Your code dangerously injects arbitrary data into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems here.  The first is that you're using `$.each()`, when there's only one image coming back.  There's a single object... nothing to iterate over.  Don't use it.

The next problem you have is that you're simply concatenating data into HTML.  By doing this, you potentially create invalid HTML, and might even risk code injection into your page.  Instead, you should create elements and set their attributes.  Try this instead:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=KmKClvkvdi3Ug54cIAhw8sd43XnYVitmTz2lAjGw').then(function(data) {
  $('.photos').append(
    $('<img>').attr('src', data.hdurl)
  );
})
```

I'll leave it up to you to decide what other attributes to set, and where to set the text.  (By the way, when you do set text, use the `.text()` method to set it.  Again, concatenating text in the context of HTML will lead to that text being interpreted as HTML!

Answer (score 0):

You can hit the URL to review the content.  It does not return an array of items, but your variable key is spelled wrong

explanation vs explaination

```
a.href = photo.hdurl (highdef)
a.alt = photo.title
p = photo.explanation
img.src = photo.url (not copyright)
```